# I'm trying to copy one text file to another using c

Tags: c

I'm trying to copy one test file to another in C. However my code is not working the program runs fine and produces a file CircleCode_temp but there is nothing in the text file. Any ideas why its not working

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   char c; 

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {

  FILE *orginalFile = fopen("CircleCode1", "r");
  FILE *newFile = fopen("CircleCode_temp", "w");


    if (orginalFile == NULL | newFile == NULL)
     {
       printf("Cannot open file");
       exit(0);
     }


      while((c = fgetc(orginalFile))!=EOF)
      {
         fputc(c,newFile);
         c = fgetc(orginalFile);
       }


      fclose(orginalFile);
      fclose(newFile);

     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `if (orginalFile == NULL | newFile == NULL)` ==> `if (orginalFile == NULL || newFile == NULL)`

Comment: `EOF` cannot be contained in a `char`, you'd need an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  while((c = fgetc(orginalFile))!=EOF)
  {
     fputc(c,newFile);
     c = fgetc(orginalFile);
   }
```

Two mistakes here:

1. You call `fgetc` twice in the loop, which throws every other character away.
2. You compare `c` to `EOF`. You're suppose to compare the return value of `fgetc` to `EOF`. If you think they're the same, remember that `c` is of type `char` and `fgetc` returns an `int`.

Also:

```
    if (orginalFile == NULL | newFile == NULL)
```

One mistake here. You have `|` which is bitwise OR, but you want `||`, which is a logical OR.

Comment: and, the bitwise OR should be logical OR.